# wmic show last logon name from file comp_names.txt

Tags: windows, batch-file

Have a script in .bat for view last logon name from list:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cnt=0
  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A IN ("m_names.txt") DO (
     echo [%%A]
       wmic /node: %%A COMPUTERSYSTEM GET dnshostname,USERNAME /all
)
```

In m_names.txt :

```
lazar2
counter683
machine
localm
etc
```

May be another way to call wmic service ?

Comment: What is the reason that you would like to *call the wmic service in another way*?

Comment: MB easy way? Have anoter post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404466/delete-shares-excluding-c-d-admin-etc     and user MC ND wrote anoter way.